# How to enable completiion in Coda like Textmate & Notepad++?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, coda

Textmate & Notepad++ can complete all words which appeared in the current document, how to enable this in Coda?

e.d. I have typed "some_text" in a document, then when I type "some_" then press ESC - "some_text" should appear in the suggestions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-complete in Coda is automatically enabled, and as far as I know, it can't be disabled. It is a lot like Dreamweaver with auto-complete, it will show you your starting tags and should automatically close some tags.

As for words, I'm pretty sure that it doesn't do that.

Comment: Both "auto" and "non-auto" are OK, I need it complete words appeared in the current document :(

Comment: From what I know it only does syntax suggestions for auto-complete. I may be wrong so it's worth shooting them an email asking or checking more on their support section: http://www.panic.com/coda/support.html

Comment: Yeah, I have asked them for this, but there is no feedback yet, thanks :)